# Raw File path access of file at JavaScript in Android 11.(scoped-storage)

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, xmlhttprequest

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

**Device name:**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; Pixel 3a Build/RPB1.200504.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36

1)android targetSdkVersion 30 requestLegacyExternalStorage = false.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ui"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        }
     }
    }
```

2. file path or URL
   lFileUrl = file:///data/user/0/com.example.ui/files/KK&T SEW_temp/IMG-20200630-223714.jpg

XMLHttpRequest request done from javascript level in cordova based android app.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", lFileUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
UI.Util.info("PtxUtils.getInlineAttachmnetJson() >> inside xhr.open");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
try {
UI.Util.info("PtxUtils.getInlineAttachmnetJson() >> inside xhr.onload");
}
```

3)XMLHttpRequest throwing error

```
ERR_ACCESS_DENIED, when getFilesDir() API used.
PtxUtils.js:2950 GET 

file:///data/user/0/com.example.ui/files/KK&T%20SEW_temp/IMG-20200630-223714.jpg net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

23:09:57.058 PtxUtils.js:2950 XHR failed loading: GET "file:///data/user/0/com.example.ui/files/KK&T%20SEW_temp/IMG-20200630-223714.jpg".
```

4)XMLHttpRequest throwing error

```
ERR_ACCESS_DENIED, when getExternalFilesDir()() API used.

PtxUtils.js:2950 GET file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.ui/files/KK&T%20SEW_temp/IMG-20200701-135735.jpg net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

PtxUtils.js:2950 XHR failed loading: GET "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.ui/files/KK&T%20SEW_temp/IMG-20200701-135735.jpg".
```

5)android targetSdkVersion 29 requestLegacyExternalStorage = false

```
with getFilesDir() path getExternalFilesDir() XMLHttpRequest is pass with no error, file data is retrieved.
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you will probably need the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And also for good measure I would also try:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and put this in Manifest :

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

**Additionally, after you make the changes clear data, uninstall the app, re-install, and try again.**

Finally, if you are using webview anywhere, also do this:

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```